# Using vuetify custom sass variables in a vue app using rails/webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, vuetify.js, webpacker

I'm working on a Vue app with Rails backend. I'm using Vuetify and I want to customize the SCSS variables. Sadly, I can't use Vue-CLI because we're bundling everything with webpacker, the rails implementation for webpack. Thus, I try to implement it with the base webpack configuration option.

I haven't been able to do this directly, as webpacker has their own css/sass/scss loader configurations. But, I *can* hook into the existing loaders and modify the options in a function that sets them later:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js

const updateStyleLoaders = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    const loader = environment.loaders.get(item);

    // Use vue-style-loader instead of default to parse Vue SFCs
    const styleConfig = loader.use.find((el) => el.loader === 'style-loader');
    if (styleConfig !== undefined) {
      styleConfig.loader = 'vue-style-loader';
    }

    // VUETIFY: Use Dart-Sass and Fibers for Sass loaders
    const sassConfig = loader.use.find((el) => el.loader === 'sass-loader');
    if (sassConfig !== undefined) {
      const opts = sassConfig.options;

      opts.implementation = require('sass'); // Use dart-sass instead of node-sass
      opts.fiber = require('fibers'); // improves compilation speed
      opts.data = "@import '@/assets/sass/variables.scss';"; // Import custom variables
    }
  });
};

// Call fuction for all css-related loaders
updateStyleLoaders(['sass', 'css', 'moduleCss', 'moduleSass']);


// @/assets/sass/variables.scss

$body-font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive; // just wanna have fun
$border-radius-root: 20px;
```

Now here's the problem:

The sass-loader rule matches both 'sass' and 'scss'. In [vuetify's example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/) the matching for sass and scss is done seperately. When I add the semicolon, I get this error during compilation:

```
./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VAlert/VAlert.sass
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

// Imports
                                     ^
      Semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax.
  ╷
1 │ @import '@/assets/sass/variables.scss';
  │                                       ^
  ╵
  stdin 1:39  root stylesheet
```

This tells me the line is in fact correctly added by sass-loader to the vuetify components that are added in. But, **when I remove the semicolon** from the import statement to support sass' indented syntax, **I see no style changes**.

How would I customize my vuetify components in this scenario? Webpacker uses sass-loader v7.3.1.

Comment: Just after finally asking a question, I came across this github discussion: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2235

Will be updating with new findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2235#issuecomment-524527397), I've got it working.

The default loaders can be removed with `environment.loaders.delete('sass') // same for 'moduleSass', 'moduleCss', 'css'`.

Then, they can be replaced by new ones. I've separated the scss and sass loaders to their own files:

```
// config/webpack/loaders/sass.js
const { config } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  test: /\.sass$/,
  use: [
    config.extract_css === false
      ? 'vue-style-loader'
      : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 2,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        implementation: require('sass'),
        fiber: require('fibers'),
        data: '@import "app/frontend/src/assets/styles/variables.scss"',
      },
    },
  ],
};

// config/webpack/loaders/scss.js

const { config } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    config.extract_css === false
      ? 'vue-style-loader'
      : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 2,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        implementation: require('sass'),
        fiber: require('fibers'),
        data: '@import "app/frontend/src/assets/styles/variables.scss";',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

These re-implement the basic webpacker integrations with CSS extraction.

Then, I add them to the main config like so:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const path = require('path');

// Plugins
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');

// Loaders
const erb = require('./loaders/erb');
const sass = require('./loaders/sass');
const scss = require('./loaders/scss');
const vue = require('./loaders/vue');
const yml = require('./loaders/yml');

// Remove webpacker's conflicting loaders
environment.loaders.delete('moduleSass');
environment.loaders.delete('moduleCss');
environment.loaders.delete('sass');

// Modify base css loader to support vue SFC style tags
environment.loaders.get('css').use.find((el) => el.loader === 'style-loader').loader = 'vue-style-loader';

// Apply plugins
environment.plugins.prepend('VuetifyLoaderPlugin', new VuetifyLoaderPlugin());
environment.plugins.prepend('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin());

// Apply custom loaders
environment.loaders.append('erb', erb);
environment.loaders.append('yml', yml);
environment.loaders.append('vue', vue);
environment.loaders.append('sass', sass);
environment.loaders.append('scss', scss);

// Shorthands for import statements
environment.config.resolve.alias = {
  // Use the same vue package everywhere
  vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm',
  // use '@' as absolute path from /src
  '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../app/frontend/src/'),
};

module.exports = environment;
```

One important part here as well is where I still modify the default css-loader to use 'vue-style-loader' over 'style-loader'. But for larger changes (like vuetify) I'm able to define my own defined loaders for SASS / SCSS syntax.

Maybe it can be optimized further to remove the duplication, but as long as it's only two configurations, I'm just happy it works :)

Comment: Do u know how this can be achieved in a project not using webpacker? I dont have an environment.js file, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143692/vuetify-without-vue-cli-sass-scss-conflict

Answer (score 1):

I just had a very similar problem about 2 days ago while trying to configure Storybook to work in a Vue/Vuetify project. Very frustrating. Here's what my working `webpack.config.js` file looks like now:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      // 'sass-loader'
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sassOptions: {
            indentedSyntax: true, // <-- THIS WAS THE KEY!
          },
          // NOTE: NO SEMICOLON USED
          prependData: `@import '${path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'scss', 'variables.scss')}'`,
        },
      },
    ],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  })

  return config
}
```

I've never used `webpacker` but based on what you've posted, I would try something like this:

```js
const updateStyleLoaders = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    const loader = environment.loaders.get(item);

    // Use vue-style-loader instead of default to parse Vue SFCs
    const styleConfig = loader.use.find((el) => el.loader === 'style-loader');
    if (styleConfig !== undefined) {
      styleConfig.loader = 'vue-style-loader';
    }

    // VUETIFY: Use Dart-Sass and Fibers for Sass loaders
    const sassConfig = loader.use.find((el) => el.loader === 'sass-loader');
    if (sassConfig !== undefined) {
      const opts = sassConfig.options;

      opts.implementation = require('sass'); // Use dart-sass instead of node-sass
      opts.fiber = require('fibers'); // improves compilation speed

      // ADD THIS LINE
      opts.sassOptions.indentedSytax = true;
      // OR MAYBE THIS ONE???
      opts.indentedSyntax = true;

      // THEN REMOVE THE SEMICOLON (or keep the semicolon and set indentedSyntax to false?)
      opts.data = "@import '@/assets/sass/variables.scss'"; // Import custom variables
    }
  });
};
```

[Full docs for all of the options available to `sass-loader` are here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader). FWIW, I find webpack configuration to be one of the most challenging things I face. It's definitely playing programming on hard mode!

I think you're close. Would love to know what configuration finally solves it.

Comment: I got it working, but thanks for the response! Forcing the loader to convert scss files to the indented syntax would probably work as well to avoid semicolon shenanigans! `opts.indentedSyntax` would be the way to go with sass-loader 7 :)