# Vuetify without vue-cli sass/scss conflict

Tags: css, webpack, sass, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to integrate vuetify into a project which can not use vue cli and has the following css/sass webpack config.

```
{
    test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {url: false, sourceMap: true}
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {sourceMap: true}
      }
    ]
}
```

Vuetify config from docs

```
{
    test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          implementation: require('sass'),
          // webpackImporter: false,
          sassOptions: {
            fiber: require('fibers'),
            indentedSyntax: true
          },
          prependData: "@import 'src/novosales/variables/scss/vuetifyCustomStyles.scss'"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

After merging into existing config

```
{
    test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {url: false, sourceMap: true}
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          implementation: require('sass'),
          sourceMap: true,
          sassOptions: {
            fiber: require('fibers'),
            indentedSyntax: true
          },
          prependData: "@import 'src/novosales/variables/scss/vuetifyCustomStyles.scss'",
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

I get error

[image]

While trying to solve I also got (expected linebreak) error, cant produce it right now.

I found a solution online but thats when using vue cli which is

```
// vue.config.js
css: {
  loaderOptions: {
    sass: {
      data: '@import "~@/sass/main.scss"',
      implementation: require("sass"),
      fiber: require("fibers")
    }
  },
  sourceMap: true
},
chainWebpack: config => {
  ["vue-modules", "vue", "normal-modules", "normal"].forEach((match) => {
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf(match).use('sass-loader')
        .tap(opt => Object.assign(opt, { data: `@import '~@/sass/main.scss';` }))
  });
}
```

I cant figure out how to achieve the same in this project and separate sass/scss.
Anyone already using vuetify without vue cli? thanks.

Comment: In my setup I'd get the same issue as you where the .sass interpreter fails on detecting a semicolon. I was unable to use the same chain (one that matches `/.s?[ca]ss/` files), but i was able to use a chain specifically for `.sass` and `.scss` separately. Duplicate the config, one for scss, one for sass, and make slight alterations as necessary (semicolons, test) for each. I hope it helps.

Comment: Separating config for sass and scss works but I wanted to achieve this with single webpack "test" so I would be sure that nothing else has changed, thanks.